# How to open Popover manually (Headless UI)

Tags: reactjs, headless-ui

Hi im currently running an e-commerce site where i need to open the cart (popover component) manually whenever a person adds something to their cart.

This is the code i have at the moment, but it's not finished. Im using Headless UI from Tailwind.

```
  export default function Cart() {
  const {isCartOpen, openCart, closeCart} = useCartUI();
  const {lines, totalQuantity} = useCart();

  return (
    <Popover className="ml-4 flow-root text-sm lg:relative lg:ml-8">
      {({open}: {open: boolean}) => {
        if(!open) closeCart();
        return (
          <>
            <Popover.Button
              className={clsx(
                'flex h-[2.4rem] items-center rounded-sm bg-darkGray px-3 py-2 text-sm font-bold duration-150',
                open ? "bg-opacity-20" : "bg-opacity-0 hover:bg-opacity-10",
              )}
            >
              <span className="mr-2">Kurv</span>
              <ChevronDownIcon className={clsx(open && 'rotate-180')} />
            </Popover.Button>

            {isCartOpen && (
              <Popover.Panel static className="absolute inset-x-0 top-16 mt-px bg-white pb-6 shadow-lg sm:px-2 lg:top-full lg:left-auto lg:right-0 lg:mt-3 lg:-mr-1.5 lg:w-80 lg:rounded-lg lg:ring-1 lg:ring-black lg:ring-opacity-5">
                <CartHeader numLines={lines.length} />
                {totalQuantity === 0 ? (
                  <CartEmpty />
                ) : (
                  <>
                    <CartItems />
                    <CartFooter />
                  </>
                )}
              </Popover.Panel>
            )}   
          </>
        )
      }}
    </Popover>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was just looking for a similar answer. If you haven't solved it, and are still interested, I found a solution.

You can use the **static** prop on the popover to always display it and use your own state, or the popover's internal state, to conditionally display its contents.

Here's an example https://codesandbox.io/s/d8llw?file=/src/App.js:600-609. You can find information on the **static** prop here: https://headlessui.com/react/popover#showing-hiding-the-popover